# Montar array com dados txt

Tags: php, array, parser

Estou tentando encontrar um jeito de montar uma tabela com os dados de um txt, mas não sei como separar os valores no array, tendo em vista que eles estão separados por vários espaços, porém são identificados por campos (Nome: , Código: , ...);

Exemplo de um arquivo txt:

```
 Código: 808                         Nome Abreviado: 091/0007756       Cliente Cobrança: 808
Nome: Nome da empresa                          Representante: 8
              Endereço: AV.2422                                                Bairro: Jardim
                Cidade: Jacare                         UF: SP                    Caixa Postal:
                  País: BRASIL                                 CEP: 12222222                  Zip Code:
           Telefone[1]: 00-0000-0000                        Telex:                            CGC/CPF: 123.321.123.4
        Ramo Atividade:                                      Grupo: 99                Data Implantação: 03/09/2007
             Categoria:                        Inscrição Municipal:
    Inscrição Estadual: 111.222.333.-74
                E-mail:  teste@teste.com
```

Comment: Cada campo está em uma linha ou existe uma limitação de caracteres por coluna?

Comment: O campos estao em linha, exatamente do jeito que esta no post, na primeira linha tem o Codigo, nome abreviado e cliente, na proxima tem o Nome, representante e assim vai. O que tem em comum entre os campos é o :.

Comment: Acho difícil um parser para esse caso, como definir o fim do campo e início do próximo? Existem tabulações para a separação dos campos?

Comment: O pior é que nao existe. Eu fiz um teste aqui e ate deu para separar os campos com base no :, o que resultou em:Array
(
    [0] =>  Código
    [1] =>  747 Nome Abreviado
    [2] =>  2M Cliente Cobrança
    [3] =>  747

)

Comment: O array não pode ser exatamente o `nome dos campos` + `:` e depois dar um trim no conteúdo que está entre isto? É só uma ideia que veio na minha imaginação !!!

Comment: verifica o padrão utilizado pelo programa q exportou esse arquivo, depois aplica a engenharia reversa

Comment: Esse é um arquivo de remessa de um banco ?

Comment: Sim, esse é um resultado de um programa que faz consulta em banco de dados, mas nao sei como ele trabalha, meu acesso a ele se limita apenas ao resultado que é arquivo txt.

Comment: Se possível, poste um exemplo de código funcional que você tenha usado, ajuda muito a formular uma resposta.

Comment: @Thiago se esse é um arquivo de remessa ou de retorno de banco você está pegando o arquivo errado, esse arquivo não foi feito para maquinas, qualquer parse ai está fardado a falhar já que algum nome pode ter ":" ou dois espaços e não há marcação ou carácter de escape. Sugiro que você entre em contato com o banco para saber como recuperar o arquivo correto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base no seu arquivo texto, consegui fazer o split em um array como você precisa:

```
$txt = ' Código: 808                         Nome Abreviado: 091/0007756       Cliente Cobrança: 808
Nome: Nome da empresa                          Representante: 8
              Endereço: AV.2422                                                Bairro: Jardim
                Cidade: Jacare                         UF: SP                    Caixa Postal:
                  País: BRASIL                                 CEP: 12222222                  Zip Code:
           Telefone[1]: 00-0000-0000                        Telex:                            CGC/CPF: 123.321.123.4
        Ramo Atividade:                                      Grupo: 99                Data Implantação: 03/09/2007
             Categoria:                        Inscrição Municipal:
    Inscrição Estadual: 111.222.333.-74
                E-mail:  teste@teste.com';

// identificar campos em branco, campos com 2 espaços após o : e separar os campos com uma barra em pé |
$txt = preg_replace(array('/:[\s]{3,}/','/:[\s]{1,2}/','/[\s]{2,}|[\r\n]/'), array(':NULL|',':','|'), $txt);

// fatiar no : e na |
$campos = preg_split("/[:\|]/", $txt);

// rodar todo o array fatiado de 2 em 2, populando o array final
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($campos);$i += 2)
    $data[trim($campos[$i])] = ($campos[$i+1] == 'NULL' ? NULL : trim($campos[$i+1]) );

print_r($data);

/* retorno:

Array
(
    [Código] => 808
    [Nome Abreviado] => 091/0007756
    [Cliente Cobrança] => 808
    [Nome] => Nome da empresa
    [Representante] => 8
    [Endereço] => AV.2422
    [Bairro] => Jardim
    [Cidade] => Jacare
    [UF] => SP
    [Caixa Postal] => 
    [País] => BRASIL
    [CEP] => 12222222
    [Zip Code] => 
    [Telefone[1]] => 00-0000-0000
    [Telex] => 
    [CGC/CPF] => 123.321.123.4
    [Ramo Atividade] => 
    [Grupo] => 99
    [Data Implantação] => 03/09/2007
    [Categoria] => 
    [Inscrição Municipal] => 
    [Inscrição Estadual] => 111.222.333.-74
    [E-mail] => teste@teste.com
)
*/
```

Comment: Eu tinha comentado que o negócio era meio pra esse lado de colocar as informações como array. Bravoooooooooo